# Sensor resolution and ISO performance

Tags: sensor, iso, resolution, noise, megapixels

I keep hearing that

> less megapixels = better ISO performance, because larger pixels capture more light

Suppose I shot something with a 4MP sensor and then downscale it to 1MP (4-to-1 pixel binning?). Would that give me the same noise performance of a 1MP sensor of same size and technology? Since noise would average out when downscaling.

In other words, are high res sensors still better because they...

1. can capture more detail in good lighting conditions
2. result in same quality shot in low-light (after downscaling)

PS: Of course, I would rather use a denoise algorithm over downscaling. I'm just trying to understand if the above argument is valid.

Comment: What kind of display device are you using? A monitor? What is its resolution? A print? What size and what ppi/dpi capability does the printer have? Are you "pixel peeping" at 100% (which means you're magnifying the higher resolution image by a greater enlargement factor than the lower resolution image)?